# best method to cast bewteen vnl_matrix<int> and vnl_matrix<double>

Tags: c++

In C++, I have a class that returns a `vnl_matrix<int>` and a second that needs a `vnl_matrix<double>` as input. Is there a straightforward method to cast from `vnl_matrix<int>` to `vnl_matrix<double>`, apart from casting each element of my matrix one by one in a double loop ?

EDIT: The constructor of the matrix based on another matrix looks is the following (I didn't write it, see [here](http://www.lems.brown.edu/vision/vxl_doc/html/core/vnl/html/classvnl__matrix.html) for details. Is it possible to modify this constructor to allow "copy/cast"

```
//: Creates a new matrix and copies all the elements.
// O(m*n).

template <class T>
vnl_matrix<T>::vnl_matrix (vnl_matrix<T> const& from)
: num_rows(from.num_rows), num_cols(from.num_cols)
{
  vnl_matrix_construct_hack();
  if (from.data && from.data[0]) {
    vnl_matrix_alloc_blah();
    T const *src = from.data[0];
    vcl_copy( src, src + this->num_rows * this->num_cols, this->data[0] );
  }
  else {
    num_rows = 0;
    num_cols = 0;
    data = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to cast the one to the other is if you had such a constructor:

```
template <typename T>
class vnl_matrix {
    // conversion
    template <typename U,
              typename = std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U,T>::value>::type>
    vnl_matrix(const vnl_matrix<U>& rhs);
};
```

That constructor would, presumably, cast all of the cells in the matrix in a loop. But you would have to add that - there's no default mechanism for this. Similarly, note that there's no way to "cast" from `vector<int>` to `vector<unsigned int>` either - you'd have to manually construct a new vector there.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I've added the constructor which I think could be modified, but it use the same template for input and output

Comment: I will try to modify it according to your suggestion and I 'll let you know